# Get unique values from a column only from lines starting with certain string in csh using awk

Tags: awk, csh

I am trying to obtain a list of hosts from this influxdb query:

```
$ influx -database "collectd" -execute "SHOW TAG VALUES WITH KEY=host"
```

The output is something like:

```
name: system
key   value
------------
host  foo.tld
host  bar.tld

name: mem
key   value
------------
host  foo.tld
host  bar.tld

...
```

Currently, I am using `awk` like this:

```
$ db-query | awk '/^host/ && !a[$2]++ { print $2 }'
```

This works when using shell `sh` and returns only the list of unique hosts, for example:

```
foo.tld
bar.tld
```

But when using `csh` shell I get this error:

```
a[: Event not found.
```

Any idea how to achieve this being portable in both `sh` and `csh` shells?

Comment: sh and csh are different languages. It seems equivalent to wanting to write code that both perl and python can run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping any/all `!` chars like `\!`

The `csh` interprets the `!` char as events in the command history.

The most common "events" used are  `!!` (previous line), and `!$` (last word in previous line), but there are a million more.

I'm surprised you're getting that error msg, as I thought csh honored single-quotes.(but apparently not;-) ).

IHTH